# display part of DataGrid of Form to another

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 5 columns Binded to observablecollection in Form1 I want to display 3 columns of it in Form2 but with condition.

**Form1**

```
+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+
|    C1    |    C2    |    C3    |    C4    |    C5    |
+==========+==========+==========+==========+==========+
```

**Form2**

```
+==========+==========+==========+
|    C1    |    C3    |    C4    |
+==========+==========+==========+
```

but with condition in the rows where (C2!=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (there are many) is to filter out the items from your `ObservableCollection`that meet your conditions, like so:

```
var filtered = DbCollection.Where(r => r.C2 !=0)
```

Then pass this to your Form2 for display

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a `CollectionViewSource`  `Form1CVS` that is based on your `ObservableCollection`  `myCollection` being used in your 1st Form, now create a new  `CollectionViewSource`  `Form2CVS` also based on `myCollection` and use it for your 2nd Form, now use its `View` to filter any condition that you need to filter by

```
CollectionViewSource Form2CVS= (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("Form2CVS");
Form2CVS.Source = myCollection;

//or
//CollectionViewSource Form2CVS = new CollectionViewSource { Source=myCollection};

ICollectionView filteredView = Form2CVS.View;

filteredView.Filter = CustomFilter
```

```
private bool CustomFilter(object item)
{
    YourClass yourObject = item as YourClass ;
    return yourObject.C2 != 0;
}
```

Comment: I bit of new can't find all the answer here